# Portable Python - getting Django to work on Apache?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am using Windows 7, Apache 2.28 and Web Developer Server Suite for my server.

All files are stored under C:/www/vhosts

I downloaded Portable Python 2.7 from http://www.portablepython.com/ and have installed it to

C:/www/portablepython

I'm trying to find mod_wsgi to get it to work with 2.7 - but how can I do this?

The reason I'm doing all this is to get a basic site running that uses Python coding, with a view to using Django, in the same way that http://www.heart.co.uk/westmids/ or http://www.capitalfm.com/birmingham do. Obviously my site won't be as advanced as theirs, but you get the gist of it; I'm using Python/Django as a sort of CMS for a news/articles website.

In any case, here's my code from C:/www/vhosts/localhost/testing.py:

```
#!/www/portablepython
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head>"
print ""
print "</head><body>"
print "Hello."
print "</body></html>"
```

This generates a 403 Forbidden error, i.e.:

**You don't have permission to access /testing.py on this server.**

I followed http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows but renamed modwsgi-version-number-datedownload.so to modwsgi.so so did that cause the error?

What do I need to do to prevent this re-occurring?

I used the Portable version for testing purposes, thinking that I can just delete the folder, and I can install again if necessary without adding to environment variables (I think portable ones do this, correct me if I'm wrong)?

What, if any changes do I need to make? Do I need to make them to the vhosts in httpd-vhosts.conf [my virtual hosts] or elsewhere?

Any help is appreciated; I'll post more as this situation develops.

Answer (score 1):

The script you have at C:/www/vhosts/localhost/testing.py is a CGI script and not a WSGI script. Follow the instructions for configuring mod_wsgi and what a WSGI script file for hello world should look like at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

Answer (score 0):

also, you should look into using a system install of python from python.org and pip+distribute+virtualenv to keep contained python environments for your different sites. This will give you maximum portability.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample - [PortableWinPy](https://github.com/yn-coder/PortableWinPy) - how to get Django work with Apache and `mod_wsgi`, in portale way.